# Django dynamic model properties

Tags: python, django, dynamic, properties, translation

I'm trying to add dynamic model properties to a Django model but it somehow doesn't work and ends up overwriting the properties.

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I want to be able to write mymodel.title_de and django internally has to query the databse and get the correct translation.

**Simplified example code (models.py)**

```
class Translation(models.Model):
    def get_prototype(self, model, cache_id, default, lang=None):
        if not lang:
            lang = get_language()

        cached = cache.get('%s_%s_%s' % (cache_id, self.id, lang))
        if not cached:
            try:
                cached = model.objects.get(quiz_id=self.id, lang=lang).translation
                cache.set('%s_%s_%s' % (cache_id, self.id, lang), cached, 60*60)
                return cached
            except model.DoesNotExist:
                return default
        else:
            return cached


class MyModel(Translation):
    # lots of things
    pass


class MyModelTrans(models.Model):
    mymodel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=settings.LANGUAGES, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('mymodel', 'lang')
        abstract = True


class MyModelTitleTrans(MyModelTrans):
    translation = models.TextField()


mymodel_attr_mapping = {
    'title': [MyModelTitleTrans, 'qtitle', ''],
}

for key in mymodel_attr_mapping.keys():
    def attr_general(self):
        return self.get_prototype(
            mymodel_attr_mapping[key][0],
            mymodel_attr_mapping[key][1],
            mymodel_attr_mapping[key][2])

    setattr(MyModel, key, property(attr_general))

    for l in settings.LANGUAGES:
        def attr_lang(self):
            return self.get_prototype(
                mymodel_attr_mapping[key][0],
                mymodel_attr_mapping[key][1],
                mymodel_attr_mapping[key][2], l[0])
        setattr(MyModel, '%s_%s' % (key, l[0]), property(attr_lang))
```

**Expected result**

```
m = MyModel()
m.save()

mtt = MyModelTitleTrans.objects.create(mymodel=m, lang='de', translation='hallo')
mtt.save()

m.title_de
>>> 'hallo'
```

**Current result**

Empty string

**Bonus question**

Is there any other way to achieve this? Unfortunalety I cannot change the way how the translation is being queried (*m.title_de*)

Thanks alot for any ideas in advance!

Comment: This may not answer the question on how to create dynamic properties, but have you considered using something like http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org ?

Comment: that's exactly the legacy code I have to get away from... ;)

Comment: matthias, can it be `abstract = True` which is breaking the logic? because model inheritance and abtract classes with custom managers dont dance together that well.. (even though you dont have custom manager here.. just guessing..)

Comment: yea, you could be right!

Answer (score 0):

Property should work and it works indeed. Lets boil it down to:

```
setattr(MyModel, 'title_de', property(lambda self: 'hallo'))
```

That way you'll get your expected result.

So look for the problem in `MyModel` logic or try to clean your cache.